# Jboss Logging issue

Tags: jboss, log4j

our application is deployed on jboos As 4.0x, we face some issues in jboss logging.. whenever the server is

restarted,

jboss stops logging , and there is no update in server.log. After that it is not updating the log file.

then we do touch cmd on log4j.xml, so that it creates the log files again.

Help me in fixing the issue we can't do touch everytine.

we face this issue in both the nodes.

Comment: Post the content of the log4j.xml file here

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if you have turned off any one of JBoss services. Please recheck if all JBoss services are ON.